# $V\cong V^{**}$ and intuition behind its consequence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $V^{**}$ is the dual of the dual space. We can prove that $V\cong V^{**}$. This isomorphism allows us to treat vectors as a member of  $V^{**}$ that is $v\in V$ can take $\phi \in V^{*}$ (a covector) as input and spit out a real number.

I have read topics like **[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710094/intuition-behind-isomorphic-spaces-being-the-same)** that explain why isomorphic spaces are treated as being the same. But still, I cannot wrap my head around the idea of treating $v$ as a member of $V^{**}$. We know that $f \in V^{**}$ is $f:V^{*}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which basically is a linear functional. $v$ is a vector and $f$ is a functional, this idea of being the same seems opaque to me since $v$ and $f$ are fundamentally different objects in nature.

I am looking for a better explanation or probably examples that illuminate the relation between the two spaces and as a result between objects of the two spaces so that I can finally say AHA!

Answer (score 2):

The two spaces are obviously not equal by the rules of set theory, and any decent professor should mention this fact in a basic linear algebra course. However, the two spaces are very naturally isomorphic. Every vector $v\in V$ defines an element $f_v\in V^{**}$ given by $f_v(\varphi)=\varphi(v)$. The fact that this is an isomorphism means that the correspondene $v\to f_v$ is bijective, and all the vector space operations are preserved:

$f_{v+w}=f_v+f_w$

$f_{\lambda v}=\lambda f_v$ for $\lambda\in F$

So what is really the difference between the two spaces? Everything is exactly the same, up to a different notation: using $f_v$ instead of $v$. Other than that, totally same properties. The isomorphism is also very natural. (to define this precisely we need to go into categories, but intuitively it means we don't even need to choose a basis in order to define this isomorphism. This is clearly the most natural correspondence between $V$ and its double dual)

At some point (again, this should **not** be done in a linear algebra course where students never saw anything like that before) we just get tired of using the notation $f_v$, and we start denoting this vector simply by $v$. We know this is not the vector $v$ itself, it is the map $V^*\to F$ given that $\varphi\to\varphi(v)$. However, since they have exactly the same properties, we use this abuse of notation. This is what really meant by the "equality" $V=V^{**}$.

Comment: Why is it so important to view $v$ as a linear functional given that $V\cong V^{**}$? Why should we replace $v$ with $f \in V^{**}$ or vice versa? If the two objects are the same up to isomorphism why do we even bother?

Comment: @FreeMind Again, by definition they are not the same. We use this isomorphism only when we need it. If $V$ is finite dimensional then any linear function in $V^{**}$ has the form $f_v$ which I mentioned. That's an important fact when you want to study $V^*$.

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the use case of this isomorphism and makes it clear when we need it? An example showing that applying this isomorphism does not affect the computation would be really illuminating (Something that supports the claim that all the vector space operations are preserved in an actual example)

Answer (score 1):

You forget the most important: **finite dimension**!!!!

Otherwise the isomorphism is so clear that we often confuse $V$ with $V^{**}$. You just associate to $x$ the form $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(x)$. Beyond clearness, this iso is **canonical**, which means we don't need to make a choice of basis to have it defined, when for $V^*$ which is also the same dimension you need to fix a basis (otherwise you can have a scalar product)! Thus $V^{**}$ behaves exactly like $V$ and linear maps involving both spaces act exactly the same!

Try to show that the result is false in infinite dimension.